# How to host ASP.NET application externally?

Tags: iis, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET application that I can get to locally by going to 192.168.1.102:81/TestApp. I would like to host the application externally by going to domain.com:81/TestApp (I already have my domain pointing to my router and this works fine - I have apache running on port 80 on another server). I modified the router settings to point any request coming through port 81 to 192.168.1.102. I am still having trouble accessing the ASP.NET site (I get the error message that "This link appears to be broken"). Am I missing something? How can I redirect domain.com:81/TestApp to my ASP.NET application? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My goodness. Needed to add Windows Firewall exception for port 81. How silly. Problem solved. Good ol' winders...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're close.  Try testing each part:

- ping the domain name to confirm that it resolves to your public IP
- confirm your public IP with www.whatsmyip.org. Make sure it hasn't recently changed.
- confirm that your router is set to forwarding port 81 to 192.168.1.102
- confirm that your inside computer is still at .102
- make sure that your forwarding is from port 81 to 81 and not trying to change ports (i.e. to port 80)
- sometimes your ISP or ISP's router will block port 81 (or most ports) and won't allow the request to get to your router.  You may need to check with them to confirm that it's not blocked
- make sure that your binding on your website is set correctly.  It should be the 192.168.1.102:81 binding that you already have though.